# AJAX call to web services

Tags: javascript, web-services, asp.net-ajax

The following article on msdn provides the ASP.NET AJAX solution of calling web service with AJAX... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx like

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="_scriptManager" runat="server">
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="StockQuoteService.asmx" />
  </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And then to use the class name directly in Jscript. But when I uploaded the service on other domain and tried to do the same, it wouldn't work. Is there no way I can do it or am I missing something? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try browsing directly to the .asmx on the other domain. What do you see?

Comment: Works fine. Even works fine on normal server call. Only problem is with the AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction this is not possible. You cannot perform cross domain AJAX calls. One possible workaround is to use [JSONP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) but you will need to have a web service which supports it.

Comment: Oh, didn't understand he was trying to consume remote service, thought he uploaded the whole thing.. :-|

Answer (score 0):

You might like to give this a whirl if you are able to use Jquery:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. Just curious to know; how do they do this in jQuery? in the sense, how would they have implemented it without any server side?

Comment: @mihsathe, they use PHP to implement a server side bridge script between the domains. Then jquery simply performs a normal AJAX request to this PHP script which delegates the call to the distant domain.

Comment: oops didn't read it properly. In that case, it becomes the obvious solution. But then why should I create a web service and not implement the whole logic in the same PHP page?

Comment: and as such no need of jQuery to apply this. You can do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please install [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and monitor your request/response, it's very helpful in troubleshooting ajax and web services issues.